# Can't update my DataGridView using MySql(Xampp) System.InvalidOperationException: 'The connection is already open.'

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
    Public Class Form1
       Dim str As String = "server=127.0.0.1; uid=root; pwd=''; database=dbparkingsystem;"
       Dim con As New MySqlConnection(str)
       Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        con.Open()
        Try
            cmd = con.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "update profile FirstName=@fName, MiddleName=@mName, LastName=@lName, Position=@pos where EmployeeID=@empID"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", TextBox1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", TextBox2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mName", TextBox3.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", TextBox4.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", TextBox5.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            load()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

My server connection is fine but the only problem with my code is that I cant update an item in my DataGridView1 giving an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The connection is already open.'

the error occurs in con.Open()

Comment: The issue seems pretty obvious: you are calling `Open` on your connection object and you're getting an error message that is telling you that the connection is already open. Where's the mystery there? You should get rid of the connection and command variables at the class level altogether. Just create them where you use them and assign them to local variables. Create them with a `Using` statement and the connection is guaranteed to be closed at the end of the block.

Answer (score 0):

I have separated your data access code from you user interface code. This makes the code easier to maintain when the UI changes or the database changes.

Give your controls more descriptive names. When you return to this code months from now will you remember what is supposed to be in `TextBox4`? If it was named `txtLastName` your code would be self documenting.

Database objects should be declared in the method where they are used so they can be properly closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for us.

You are missing the `SET` keyword in you update statement.

You can pass the `.CommandText` and the `.Connection` directly to the constructor of the `Command`.

Don't open the connection until directly before the `Execute..`.

**Do Not** write empty `Catch` blocks! They only swallow errors. Your code goes astray but you are not informed.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Input validation
    Dim id As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, id) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid ID")
        Return
    End If
    'You may want to add additional validation to check if all the text boxes have data.
    Try
        UpdateProfile(id, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Update Profile Error")
    End Try
    Try
        Load()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Loading Grid")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProfile(ID As Integer, fName As String, mName As String, lName As String, pos As String)
    Dim sql = "update profile SET FirstName=@fName, MiddleName=@mName, LastName=@lName, Position=@pos where EmployeeID=@empID"
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(str),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", ID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", fName)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mName", mName)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", lName)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", pos)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using 'Closes and disposes con and cmd
End Sub
```